# Show that $x^2-\cos(x)$ has two roots in the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck in a problem. I have to show that the function $f:\;\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x)=x^2-\cos(x)$ has exaclty two roots in the real numbers.

It's also specified, as a remark, that $f$ is a function of class $C^m$.

Comment: Are you familiar with intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Yes I already saw this theorem.

Comment: Notice that $f(-\pi)>0 \ , \ f(0)<0 \ , \ f(\pi)>0$. What does IVT tells us and how could we show that there aren't any other solutions?

Comment: Ok now I understand. IVT tell us that because the function is continuous, as the remark suggest us, we have $\exists\;c_{1}\in\;]-\pi,0[$ such as $f(c_{1})=0$ For the same reason, $\exists\;c_{2}\in\;]0,\pi[$ such as $f(c_{2})=0$. I didn't thought about this theorem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if

$f(x) = x^2 - \cos x = 0, \tag{1}$

then

$x^2 = \cos x, \tag{2}$

so

$\vert x \vert^2 = \vert x^2 \vert = \vert \cos x \vert \le 1; \tag{3}$

thus any solution must satisfy

$\vert x \vert \le 1, \tag{4}$

or

$-1 \le x \le 1.  \tag{3}$

Let's look at the case $x \ge 0$; we have

$f(0) = -1, f(1) = 1 - \cos 1 > 0, \tag{4}$

since $1 < \pi / 2$; now by the intermediate value theorem we must have $f(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in (0, 1)$.  Since $x^2$ increases and $\cos x$ decreases, both monotonically, on $(0, 1)$, there can only be this one point $x_0$ where their graphs intersect; only one point where $f(x_0) = 0$.  Now use reflection symmetry across the $y$-axis (i.e., that $f(x)$ is even) to see that $-x_0$ is the only other solution.

We didn't even need the fact that $f(x) \in C^m$, though in fact it is analytic!

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to verify that $f$ is an even function. Thus if $z$ is a root, then $-z$ is also a root. We only need to show that there is exactly one positive value for $z$. (Then the other one is of course $-z$.)

We can write $f(x) = 0$ or $x^2 = \cos(x)$. Then we know that $x$ is between $0$ and $1$, since $|\cos(\cdot)|\leq 1$. But because $x^2$ is strictly increasing in this domain and $\cos(\cdot)$ is strictly decreasing, we can only find one solution. In the other (positive) domains, $x^2>cos(x)$ since $x>1\implies x^2>1 \implies x^2>\cos(x)$.

Hence, there are exactly two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, in order to check the real roots of $f(x)=x^2-\cos x$ we have $$x^2-\cos x=0\iff x^2=\cos x$$
the graphs of $y=x^2$ & $y=\cos x$ intersect each other at two different real points $x=0.824132$ & $x=-0.824132$

See in the graph below

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Note that both the functions are even, the *difference* function passes from positive, zero, negative, zero and back again to positive. There would hence be ( at least ) two roots of same magnitude but opposite sign.