# $4\cos(x) -x = 0$: There exist at least two solutions

Tags: continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

So the statement is the following: For $4\cos(x) -x = 0$ , where $x$ is a real number, prove that there exist at least two solutions.

I would like to prove the statement above statement using The intermediate value theorem, but I am not sure i should go about it, since the interval is not given. I would much appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: Good idea. What is stopping you to use the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $x^2-\cos(x)$ has two roots in the real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385024/show-that-x2-cosx-has-two-roots-in-the-real-numbers)

Comment: Superimposed the graphs of $y=4\cos x$ and $y=x$ and you will see approximately where the solutions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: evaluate the given function at the four points $x\in\{-2\pi,-\pi,0,\pi\}$
and use the Intermediate value theorem.

Note: these points were found by mere inspection of the graph.

Comment: Oh yes this worked quite nicely. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome :)